# Selectors with data attribute

Tags: testing, automated-tests, ui-automation, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm having troubles creating a selector for the button with the data-qa attribute. See html:

`<div class="stepsInfo_children__4knGx"><button type="button" class="steps_stepsButton__3Ykpu" data-qa="next-design">`

I tried this implementation, with no success (from the official documentation):
`this.nextDesign = Selector("div").withAttribute("data-qa","next-design");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alex is right, you missed it's actually a button.

Or you can avoid `withAttribute()` and create the following selector:

```
this.nextDesign = Selector('[data-qa="next-design"]');
```

it's a bit shorter, which might make it a bit more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You try to create a selector for the **button**, but you create it for a **div element**. It looks like you meant this:

```
this.nextDesign = Selector("button").withAttribute("data-qa","next-design");
```